# When does a package need to use ::: for its own objects

Tags: r, r-package

Consider this R package with two functions, one exported and the other internal

**hello.R**

```
#' @export
hello <- function() {
  internalFunctions:::hello_internal()
}
```

**hello_internal.R**

```
hello_internal <- function(x){
    print("hello world")
}
```

**NAMESPACE**

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand

export(hello)
```

---

When this is checked (`devtools::check()`) it returns the `NOTE`

```
There are ::: calls to the package's namespace in its code. A package
  almost never needs to use ::: for its own objects:
  ‘hello_internal’
```

---

#### Question

Given the `NOTE` says **almost never**, under what circumstances **will** a package need to use `:::` for its own objects?

---

**Extra**

I have a very similar [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36805601/5977215) where I do require the `:::` for an internal function, but I don't know **why** it's required. Hopefully having an answer to this one will solve that one. I have a suspicion that unlocking the environment is doing something I'm not expecting, and thus having to use `:::` on an internal function.

If they are considered duplicates of each other I'll delete the other one.

Comment: one might consider using `:::` to make it explicit (to the reader) that the function is from this package (but its not *needed*)

Answer (score 5):

You should never need this in ordinary circumstances. You may need it if you are calling the parent function in an unusual way (for example, you've manually changed its environment, or you're calling it from another process where the package isn't attached).

Comment: Hi Hadley, sure, it's not needed, but why is it discouraged by check? For  manual debugging, for example, it might be convenient to write package:::internal in the code, so that one doesn't have to load internals by hand. Ist there any downside to code with package:::internal?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pseudo-code example, where I think using ::: is the only viable solution:

```
# R-package with an internal function FInternal() that is called in a foreach loop
FInternal <- function(i) {...}

#' Exported function containing a foreach loop
#' @export
ParallelLoop <- function(is, <other-variables>) {
   foreach(i = is) %dopar% {
      # This fails, because it cannot not locate FInternal, unless it is exported.
      FInternal(i)
      # This works but causes a note:
      PackageName:::FInternal(i)
   }
}
```

I think the problem here is that the body of the foreach loop is not defined as a function of the package. Hence, when executed on a worker process, it is not treated as a code belonging to the package and does not have access to the internal objects of the package. I would be glad if someone could suggest an elegant solution for this specific case.

Comment: I am having the same issue that you had with `foreach::foreach()` when using `parallel::parLapply()`. Did you ever find an elegant solution to this? I am getting the warning, "There are ::: calls to the package's namespace in its code. A package almost never needs to use ::: for its own objects."